# Getting Value Error in Python function when calling signal.firwin

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am using Least Square filter function in python which is **firwin** and it is in signal library and when i am calling the function it is raising Value Error.

My Code Snippet:

```
Fs = 100

epochs = n/Fs

nyquist = Fs/2

lower_filter_bound = 7;

upper_filter_bound = 13;

transition_width = 0.7;

filter_order = np.round((Fs/lower_filter_bound))

idealresponse = [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 ];

filterName = 'Band pass filtered';

F = [0, (((1-transition_width)*lower_filter_bound)/nyquist), 
(lower_filter_bound/nyquist),(upper_filter_bound/nyquist),(((1+transition_width)*upper_filter_bound)/nyquist), nyquist/nyquist];

filterweights = sig.firwin(filter_order, F, idealresponse)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "File.py", line 34, in <module>
    filterweights = sig.firwin(filter_order, F, idealresponse)

raise ValueError("Invalid cutoff frequency: frequencies must be "
ValueError: Invalid cutoff frequency: frequencies must be greater than 0 and less than nyq.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least squares FIR filter design function in scipy is [`scipy.signal.firls`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firls.html) (not `scipy.signal.firwin`).

`firls` requires an odd number of taps, so you'll have to ensure that `filter_order` is odd.

---

If `firwin` is actually the function that you meant to use, then
take another look at the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html).  In particular:

- `firwin` does not take an argument for the ideal response.  It is only given the band edges in the `cutoff` argument.
- The description of the `cutoff` argument specifically says this argument must not contain 0 and the Nyquist frequency.
- You appear to be creating a bandpass filter.  There is an example of this in the docstring:

  ```
  Band-pass:

  >>> f1, f2 = 0.1, 0.2
  >>> signal.firwin(numtaps, [f1, f2], pass_zero=False)
  array([ 0.06301614,  0.88770441,  0.06301614])
  ```
- The first argument of `firwin` must be an integer, not a float.

Here's how you implement your filter using `firwin`:

```
lower = lower_filter_bound/nyquist
upper = upper_filter_bound/nyquist
filterweights = sig.firwin(int(filter_order), [lower, upper], pass_zero=False)
```

If you need more flexibility in the design of your FIR filter, take a look at [`scipy.signal.firwin2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin2.html).